# Camera onPreviewFrame Resolution (Nexus 4)

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to get a 1920 x 1080 jpeg onPreviewFrame.

The size of the frame on onPreviewFrame depends on the Camera.setPictureSize/Camera.setPreviewSize(correct me if I am wrong)

Currently, when I shoot a 1080p video with the default camcorder, I am able to get a video with resolution 1920 x 1080. Therefore, I assume that I should be able to get a 1920 x 1080 frame from onPreviewFrame.

Nevertheless when I ask my Camera to print all of the supported PictureSize and Supported PreviewSize, it shows 1280 x 720 as the max size.

Because the camera said the max size is 1280 x 720, there is no way for me to capture a frame at 1920 x 1080.

Am I missing something here that prevent me from getting a 1920 x 1080 frame or is there any walk around that would allow me to setPictureSize and PreviewSize that is larger than the SupportedPictureSize and SupportedPreviewSize

Below is the log for the nexus's 4 back camera's list of supported preview and picture size.

thanks for reading and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

```
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 1280===720
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 800===480
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 768===432
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 720===480
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 640===480
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 576===432
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 480===320
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 384===288
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 352===288
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 320===240
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 240===160
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ picturesize: 176===144

11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 1280===720
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 800===480
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 768===432
11-05 13:37:57.987    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 720===480
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 640===480
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 576===432
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 480===320
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 384===288
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 352===288
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 320===240
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 240===160
11-05 13:37:57.997    5576-5576/com.example.mediacodecapp E/CamcorderProfile﹕ previewSize: 176===144
```

Comment: "Currently, when I shoot a 1080p video with the default camcorder, I am able to get a video with resolution 1920 x 1080. Therefore, I assume that I should be able to get a 1920 x 1080 frame from onPreviewFrame" -- that is not a safe assumption.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the supported preview sizes for front-facing camera ?

Comment: @CommonsWare, why does this happen?

Comment: @softwarevamp: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am facing same issue. I am trying to recording 1080P videos, but tested resolution is about 600P using 12233 test charts.

Comment: @softwarevamp: This question is about capturing preview frames, not recording videos. I am not a video recording expert, so I do not know what "12333 test charts" are. If you are having problems with camera hardware on a particular device, contact the device manufacturer. Camera hardware varies substantially from device to device, let alone from manufacturer to manufacturer.